# Is it better to set social media sharer in entry-footer.php or comments.php in Wordpress blog?

Tags: pages, comments, single, social-sharing, sharing

I'm now deciding where should I put social media sharers. Currently, I'm now putting sharers code in `entry-footer.php`. But is it more semantic to put sharers in `entry-footer.php`, in the bottom of every post, or `comments.php`, being together with comment box in Wordpress?

Also, since the `entry-footer.php` is the default structure only for *single post*, is it reasonable to ask `page.php` to load `entry-footer.php`, too? Or should I just rewrite a block of sharer codes inside `page.php`? How about loading `comments.php` with sharer codes inside?

Comment: Why not just create a separate template part for the code, or a function, and then call it where it is needed???

Comment: @PieterGoosen I'm not pretty familiar with js code or php, but this is a good idea. So can I recall a `sharer.php` inside `entry-footer.php`?

Comment: Yes you can. Just remember, js need to be enqueued via the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook